# How to select rows from a table that matches all the rows from a second table which has predicates?

Tags: mysql, join, exists

I have two tables, a transaction table and a transaction property table as follows.

transaction table

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`event` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `type` INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

property table

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`event_property` (
  `event_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `property_type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`, `property_type`, `value`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`event` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT);
```

A single event may have multiple properties. I want to select a certain event which has two properties with certain values. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select event_id
from event_property
where property_type in ('1', '2')
group by event_id
having count(distinct property_type) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This would work if I have no concern regarding what values the properties hold. But I want to put predicates on values of the property entries too. Also I want to put a predicate on the user name too.

Comment: @javabot . . . I would suggest that you add another question with more detail about what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Comment: For the life of me I can't figure out how to insert a table in the question. :(  Otherwise I would have posted sample data, without sample data its pretty hard to convey what I won't to accomplish.. I figured out a way to do this though, using exists.Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @Javabot . . . Just put four spaces before each row.  This used a fixed-width font and you can align columns using spaces.